# jsonp parsing: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'json_string

Tags: python, json

Добрый день  спарсить данные json на python?

сам json

/*jsonp*/s7ViewResponse({"set":
{"pv":"1.0","type":"img_set","n":"EBFL2/65031208","item":[{"i":{"n":"EBFL2/65031208_fr_sc7"},"s":{"n":"EBFL2/65031208_fr_sc7"},"dx":"2000","dy":"1728","iv":"bAlQr0"},{"i":{"n":"EBFL2/65031208_a1_sc7"},"s":{"n":"EBFL2/65031208_a1_sc7"},"dx":"2000","dy":"1790","iv":"n2PQj0"},{"i":{"n":"EBFL2/65031208_a2_sc7"},"s":{"n":"EBFL2/65031208_a2_sc7"},"dx":"1113","dy":"2000","iv":"_GWPF1"},{"i":{"n":"EBFL2/65031208_a3_sc7"},"s":{"n":"EBFL2/65031208_a3_sc7"},"dx":"767","dy":"2000","iv":"3IbRB0"},{"i":{"n":"EBFL2/65031208_bo_sc7"},"s":{"n":"EBFL2/65031208_bo_sc7"},"dx":"2000","dy":"784","iv":"hvpQB0"}]}},"");

на выходе должно получиться это
65031208_fr_sc7
EBFL2/65031208_fr_sc7 
EBFL2/65031208_a1_sc7

мой код

```
gh = requests.get(protimg).text
gurl = gj.json_string = {"n": ''}
ljos = json.loads(gurl)
print(ljos)
```

выходит ошибка:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/project/final-score.py", line 115, in <module>
    main()
  File "/opt/project/final-score.py", line 111, in main
    final_score()
  File "/opt/project/final-score.py", line 102, in final_score
    gurl = gh.json_string = {"n": ''}
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'json_string
```

'

```
update
```

'''
коментарии
urlimg = 'http://images.footlocker.com/is/image/EBFL2/'
prodictit = id продукта оно разное
'''

```
imggurl = urljoin(urlimg, productid)
protimg = '{url{ext}'.format(url=imggurl,ext='req=set,json&handler=s7ViewResponse&')
```

вывод

```
http://images.footlocker.com/is/image/EBFL2/65031208?req=set,json&handler=s7ViewResponse&
http://images.footlocker.com/is/image/EBFL2/6634A?req=set,json&handler=s7ViewResponse&
http://images.footlocker.com/is/image/EBFL2/A1GJB544?req=set,json&handler=s7ViewResponse&
http://images.footlocker.com/is/image/EBFL2/65031208?req=set,json&handler=s7ViewResponse&
http://images.footlocker.com/is/image/EBFL2/153662C?req=set,json&handler=s7ViewResponse&
http://images.footlocker.com/is/image/EBFL2/57937300?req=set,json&handler=s7ViewResponse&
http://images.footlocker.com/is/image/EBFL2/54554001?req=set,json&handler=s7ViewResponse&
http://images.footlocker.com/is/image/EBFL2/BM1000BK?req=set,json&handler=s7ViewResponse&
http://images.footlocker.com/is/image/EBFL2/6K1L0101?req=set,json&handler=s7ViewResponse&
http://images.footlocker.com/is/image/EBFL2/S79742?req=set,json&handler=s7ViewResponse&
http://images.footlocker.com/is/image/EBFL2/36182203?req=set,json&handler=s7ViewResponse&
http://images.footlocker.com/is/image/EBFL2/96611861?req=set,json&handler=s7ViewResponse&
http://images.footlocker.com/is/image/EBFL2/10800724?req=set,json&handler=s7ViewResponse&
http://images.footlocker.com/is/image/EBFL2/05899101?req=set,json&handler=s7ViewResponse&
http://images.footlocker.com/is/image/EBFL2/36336601?req=set,json&handler=s7ViewResponse&
http://images.footlocker.com/is/image/EBFL2/44018003?req=set,json&handler=s7ViewResponse&
http://images.footlocker.com/is/image/EBFL2/HFLPXBL?req=set,json&handler=s7ViewResponse&
http://images.footlocker.com/is/image/EBFL2/A3496LQT?req=set,json&handler=s7ViewResponse&
http://images.footlocker.com/is/image/EBFL2/AQ5518?req=set,json&handler=s7ViewResponse&
...............
```

продолжение кода

```
qr = requests.get(protimg)
j_strings = re.findall(r'({.*})', r.text)

 d = {}
    if j_strings:
    d = json.loads(j_strings[0])


    for k in d['set']['item']:
        dd = '{url}{ext}{end}'.format(url=imgurg, ext=k['i']['n'], end='?id=Y6YPH3?&wid=1280&hei=877&fmt.png')
        t = requests.get(dd)
        out = open('images/%s' % dd.split('/')[-1], 'wb')
        out.write(t.content)
        out.close()
```

когда выходит следующая ссылка у меня выходит ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/project/final-score.py", line 126, in <module>
    main()
  File "/opt/project/final-score.py", line 122, in main
    final_score()
  File "/opt/project/final-score.py", line 112, in final_score
    dd = '{url}{ext}{end}'.format(url=imgurg, ext=k['i']['n'], end='?id=Y6YPH3?&wid=1280&hei=877&fmt.png')
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Если я ссылку не генерирую то все нормально, может у меня json не может понять что это json?
Из - за чего ошибка?

решил проблему

```
try:
   for k in d['set']['item']:
      dd = '{url}{ext}{end}'.format(url=imgurg, ext=k['i']['n'], end='?id=Y6YPH3?&wid=1280&hei=877&fmt.png')
      t = requests.get(dd)
      out = open('images/%s' % dd.split('/')[-1], 'wb')
      out.write(t.content)
      out.close()
 except Exception as e:
 contine
```

Comment: Приведенный вами JSON - JSON'ом не является. Вы можете привести "валидный" JSON или исходный URL ?

Comment: [url](http://images.footlocker.com/is/image/EBFL2/05899101?req=set,json&handler=s7ViewResponse&)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что по указанному адресу находится следующая "структура":

```
/*jsonp*/s7ViewResponse(JSON_STRING,"");
```

из которой надо вычленить `JSON_STRING`:

```
import re
import json
import requests

url = 'http://images.footlocker.com/is/image/EBFL2/05899101?req=set,json&handler=s7ViewResponse&'

r = requests.get(url)

# ищем JSON в строке
#    убираем / игнорируем всё, кроме `{...}`
#    RegEx жадный поэтому искать будем все до последнего (включая) вхождения `}`
j_strings = re.findall(r'({.*})', r.text)

d = {}    
if j_strings:
    d = json.loads(j_strings[0])

print(d)
```

Результат:

```
In [33]: from pprint import pprint

In [34]: pprint(d)
{'set': {'item': [{'dx': '2023',
                   'dy': '1460',
                   'i': {'n': 'EBFL2/05899101_fr_ven_sc7'},
                   'iv': 'um_Qh3',
                   's': {'n': 'EBFL2/05899101_fr_ven_sc7'}},
                  {'dx': '2030',
                   'dy': '1466',
                   'i': {'n': 'EBFL2/05899101_a1_ven_sc7'},
                   'iv': 'eWVQ73',
                   's': {'n': 'EBFL2/05899101_a1_ven_sc7'}},
                  {'dx': '994',
                   'dy': '1999',
                   'i': {'n': 'EBFL2/05899101_a2_ven_sc7'},
                   'iv': '13gQT2',
                   's': {'n': 'EBFL2/05899101_a2_ven_sc7'}},
                  {'dx': '738',
                   'dy': '2013',
                   'i': {'n': 'EBFL2/05899101_a3_ven_sc7'},
                   'iv': 'plIQb1',
                   's': {'n': 'EBFL2/05899101_a3_ven_sc7'}},
                  {'dx': '2018',
                   'dy': '1321',
                   'i': {'n': 'EBFL2/05899101_a4_ven_sc7'},
                   'iv': '7kuQv2',
                   's': {'n': 'EBFL2/05899101_a4_ven_sc7'}},
                  {'dx': '2016',
                   'dy': '755',
                   'i': {'n': 'EBFL2/05899101_bo_ven_sc7'},
                   'iv': 'r8NQH3',
                   's': {'n': 'EBFL2/05899101_bo_ven_sc7'}}],
         'n': 'EBFL2/05899101',
         'pv': '1.0',
         'type': 'img_set'}}
```

> как распарсить его что бы получить EBFL2/05899101_fr_ven_sc7

```
In [87]: [el for el in d['set']['item'] if 'i' in el and 'EBFL2/05899101_fr_ven_sc7' in el['i'].get('n')]
Out[87]:
[{'dx': '2023',
  'dy': '1460',
  'i': {'n': 'EBFL2/05899101_fr_ven_sc7'},
  'iv': 'um_Qh3',
  's': {'n': 'EBFL2/05899101_fr_ven_sc7'}}]

In [89]: [el['i'].get('n') for el in d['set']['item']
          if 'i' in el
            and 'n' in el['i']
            and 'EBFL2/05899101_fr_ven_sc7' in el['i'].get('n')]
Out[89]: ['EBFL2/05899101_fr_ven_sc7']
```

Comment: спасибо, а как распарсить его что бы получить EBFL2/05899101_fr_ven_sc7 ?

Comment: @fermeg, я исправил ответ - я правильно вас понял?

Comment: У меня несколько тысяч json и везде данные разные, парсю все 'i': {'n': 'xxxxxxxxx'}, без  's': {'n': 'xxxxxxxxxxx'}}, так как они разные.  
данные я использую для получения ссылки картинки.
например http://url.net/slug.png

Comment: for k in test['set']['item']:
    print(k['i']['n'])

сделал так, но когда переходит на сл страницу падает?